# How to copy a website

Tags: web

I want to copy a whole website (uncopyrighted)'s contents to a Blogspot blog.

Basically if a website has a table of contents like this:

Intro (link) 
Chapter 1 (link) 
Chapter 2(link) 
etc...

How do I make a program so that automatically the links to these articles are posted to my Blogspot blog, and when I click on the links it goes to posts within my blogspot as opposed to the actual link?

So basically I want a program that does this:

When there is a series of links on a website, open link 1, copy & paste on Blogspot (on a new post) open link2, repeat until end of link,

and then create a final post that has links with the same title as the original links, to all the Blogspot posts.

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/76445309/10461328

Answer (score 1):

Blogger/Blogspot isn't the best-suited tool for this. Wouldn't it be easier to just mirror the website's content elsewhere?

```
# Mirror an entire website (-m), convert links (-k), and wait (-w) 2 seconds between requests.
wget -mk -w 2s http://www.example.com/
```

Still, if you're adamant about it, you could take a look at the **[Import/Export feature in Blogger](http://bloggerindraft.blogspot.com/2008/06/new-feature-import-and-export.html)**.

Comment: I don't know how to build a website. Can u recommend a site? Hopefully a fun one, because I was looking at one and it was boring, so that I could not follow.

Answer (score 0):

There is by definition no uncopyrighted content.

If the site you want to copy is using javascript magic then there is no easy general option, otherwise i agree with John to use "wget".

But from your question you should take a basic programming course first and come back in a few months.

Comment: That's not how the law works. The site can write what it wants, but what's on it is copyrighted.

Comment: That's not strictly true. Work that's released into the public domain has no copyright protection.

Comment: No. The construct of public domain does not exist in international law. I know that some people say that the national law of USA allows this, but i doubt it as the international copyright act which was initiated and signed by the USA makes clear that a creator can never loose the copyright on his publications. My wisdom about this is about 10 years old - but i would guess it is still correct.