# Reliable Online Manual Copy Tool

Tags: web, offline, manual

I often have to develop projects where no internet is available.

Unfortunately, more and more programs no longer have offline manuals.

What is the best way to copy an online help locally? HTTrack Website Copier fails very often.

Which windows tool is the most reliable?

Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an experience with HTTrack Website Copier then you can try an online tool called [httrack-online](https://httrack-online.com/). It can download the required webpage as a static webpage.